# developing tree hierarchy from multiple table

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring, hibernate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiXl9.jpg)

I want to build a hierarchy like this in which 1st level is from single table next level is from different table and so on. Please guide me how to start

Comment: First question you should ask yourself is what would be the relationship between entities. Anyways, please ask a question that fulfills [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this site can be helpful http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/